# How can I deploy a Node.js API on my AWS server?

Tags: node.js

I want to deploy a simple Node.js API on my AWS server.

I have added the npm dependencies with `package.json` using `npm install`.
I've also added a file named `server.js` and the content inside it is below:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/message', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});
app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

When I write `npm start` on node command prompt, `localhost:3000` opens in a browser, and on calling `localhost:3000/message` it response properly so it works fine.

Here I want to open the same (`localhost:3000/message`) on my GoDaddy domain, suppose its `abc.com`.

On the server I have installed Node.js, this code is placed in the root folder, npm dependencies are installed and the folder is added as a website using inetmgr.

Now I am calling `abc.com/message`, but I'm getting no response. What can I do w

Answer (score 0):

TO deploy a nodejs application in AWS you need to do the following things-

1. make sure your EC2 instance has a public IP associated with your domain name. And also make sure the IP is accessible from public network. You can use Route53 for this purpose but there are other plenty of resources to help you with this.
2. You can either map your application running port to a subdomain or modify instance's security policy to expose that port for public access. I found its easier and more convenient to use subdomain. You can configure this using nginx or apace virtual hosts configuration.
3. You should use pm2 to keep your application running in the background. And also include the pm2 in the startup applications list in your instance's operating system.

Some useful links-

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/route-53
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-http-https-ec2/

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pm2-to-setup-a-node-js-production-environment-on-an-ubuntu-vps

Comment: Thanks for the reply maksbd.I am using pm2 for running the application.Also when I am placing front end code instead of node api code, Like on opening login url like abc.com/login, it goes to that url and work better, but when front end code replaced with node api, api not calling here.
            I have purchased domain name from godaddy and hosting from aws, and want to run node api in the same.
            . Please suggest me step by step for route53 as I am little new in the field.

Comment: I believe this is happening because the port `3000` is not publicly accessible. Here is a nice article https://www.bogotobogo.com/DevOps/AWS/aws-Route53-DNS-Subdomain.php You need to change the _listen port number_ to which your app is running

Comment: Thanks for the time and your guidance, I follow the mentioned steps, but not succeeded, I tried to launch one more instance as linux using aws with different ip, I have added a name in godaddy account,but still issue same issue.Now I have mentioned what I have, please tell me what extra I need to launch node api, I will be very thankful for this.